# MYSQL print names by id with highest occurences in a different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a query listing the name of the staff member(s) who supervise(s) the
highest number of students. The result should also display the number of students.
The query should also work in situations when more than one supervisor has
highest students (e.g. 2 supervisors each having 10 students, 10 being highest).

Every post on stackoverflow I have read about getting the most common value all talk about just listing values by frequency of occurence and then using LIMIT to only show the top one. However I need to do it in such a way that it will show the highest one and any others that are equal to it and it has to be dynamic for a result list of any length.

There is 2 separate tables as below so I figured the query would be something like

Students table

```
+------------------+----------+
|  S_FIRST         |   F_ID   |
+------------------+----------+
| Tammy            |        1 |
| jorge            |        1 |
| john             |        1 |
| mike             |        2 |
| lisa             |        4 |
| ni               |        3 |
```

faculty table

```
+------------------+----------+
| F_FIRST          |   F_ID   |
+------------------+----------+
| Teresa           |        1 |
| mark             |        2 |
| colin            |        3 |
| jonnel           |        4 |
| james            |        5 |
```

SELECT F_FIRST, COUNT(student.F_ID) AS value_occurrence
from faculty, student
group by F_FIRST
ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC;

But that just gives the below output.

```
F_FIRST         VALUE_OCCURRENCE
--------------- ----------------
Jonnel                         6
Mark                           6
James                          6
Colin                          6
Teresa                         6
```

The expected output is

```
F_FIRST         VALUE_OCCURRENCE
--------------- ----------------
Teresa                         3
```

Comment: Don't you need to group by something? Like faculty?

Comment: Would be helpful if you'd show us some output example

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: all rows have value_occurence = 6 , which is obvious since all have the highest number?

Comment: None of them have the number 6 though nor do any of the staff have 6 students